# How do I divide a record according to the different types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this query

```
Declare @TotalThreats int;
Declare @TotalThreats_M int;
Declare @TotalThreats_H int;
Declare @TotalThreats_L int;
(Select count(E.EnggDataID) as 'Total Threats', E.Area from EngineeringData E inner join RBIResults R on R.EnggDataID=E.EnggDataID  group by E.Area)
(Select count(E.EnggDataID) as 'Total Threats M',E.Area from EngineeringData E inner join RBIResults R on R.EnggDataID=E.EnggDataID where R.RiskOverall='M' group by E.Area) 
(Select count(E.EnggDataID) as 'Total Threats H',E.Area  from EngineeringData E inner join RBIResults R on R.EnggDataID=E.EnggDataID where R.RiskOverall='H' group by E.Area )
(Select count(E.EnggDataID) as 'Total Threats L',E.Area  from EngineeringData E inner join RBIResults R on R.EnggDataID=E.EnggDataID where R.RiskOverall='L' group by E.Area) 

--Select @TotalThreats,@TotalThreats_M,@TotalThreats_H,@TotalThreats_L
```

It shows Total Threats for each area.

But each area has 3 types of overall risk i.e. **H, M, L, MH**. (Name of the columns is RiskOverall)

Now my query is ok to show **TotalThreats** according to Area but i also want to see different total H,M,L, MH.

For Example. Output should be like this

```
TotalThreats     Area   H   M   L   MH

   10             A     1   5   3   1
```

Comment: It is unclear what `MH` refers to.

Comment: MH is just an RiskOverall value

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select E.Area, count(*) as TotalThreats, 
       sum(case when R.RiskOverall = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as risk_h,
       sum(case when R.RiskOverall = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as risk_m,
       sum(case when R.RiskOverall = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) as risk_l,
       sum(case when R.RiskOverall in ('H', 'M', 'L') then 1 else 0 end) as risk_all
from EngineeringData E join
     RBIResults R
     on R.EnggDataID = E.EnggDataID
group by E.Area;
```